When using osm2pgsql to update my data, it shows my version numbers then just quits
I used osm2pgsql previously (many times) to load an OSM data file directly into my AWS database.  I just ran the same command again in the same way:
osm2pgsql C:\Users\█████\Downloads\kanto-latest.osm.pbf -c --database=osm_data 
  --port=████ --host=postgres-postgis.█████.█████.rds.amazonaws.com --latlong 
  --slim --password --user=█████ -S "C:\Program Files\osm2pgsql-bin\default.style"

and then I enter the password at the prompt as usual.
Instead of running as usual, it just reports the version numbers of three components
2024-12-18 19:44:01  osm2pgsql version 1.11.0
2024-12-18 19:44:01  Database version: 14.12
2024-12-18 19:44:01  PostGIS version: 3.1

then thinks for a second, then quits and returns to the user prompt.
I've confirmed that it's in my Path environmental variables.
I've confirmed the AWS and database settings.
The only change in my setup was that the folder was "downloads" and now it's "Downloads" (which is changed in the command).
There is no error, and no similar issue I could find on SE, so it's hard to track down the cause.
I'm hoping that somebody has encountered this problem before and was able to figure out what I'm missing.

So, I had some back and forth on github about this.
We did some debugging, but after passing various tests, the program would always just stop when it was supposed to start doing the real work.
With no error messages to trace, I just deleted my old osm2pgsql-bin and dropped in a new one (v2.0.1).  I didn't change any other setting or path variable or anything.
Then it ran with no problem.
I don't know how it is possible to have corrupted the previous installation, but there was just something wrong with my program files I guess.  If you have this problem in the future, you can bypass the debugging and just re-install the program in 30 seconds.
